# in a single column i have three values ...how to get them separately

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<table>
<tr><td>Pam Date:23-11-2014 Time: 02:18:00 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Sam Date:24-11-2014 Time: 04:00:00 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Julie  Date:26-11-2014 Time: 06:10:00 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Remo Date:27-11-2014 Time: 04:25:00 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Woods Date:27-11-2014 Time: 03:40:00 </td></tr>
</table>
```

All these values are in the same column, I need the `date` value alone.

Comment: How do you print this?

Comment: What exactly do you want? To get Date and Time separately out of your HTML? With what? JS? what is your goal? Changing data before printout with PHP? Where do you get data from? tell us more ...

Comment: Where are you getting this HTML from? Is this something that you're scraping? Or markup that you're generating yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $input = "<tr><td>Pam Date:23-11-2014 Time: 02:18:00 </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sam Date:24-11-2014 Time: 04:00:00 </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Julie  Date:26-11-2014 Time: 06:10:00 </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Remo Date:27-11-2014 Time: 04:25:00 </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Woods Date:27-11-2014 Time: 03:40:00 </td></tr>
            ";

    preg_match_all("/Date:\s?(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\s?/", $input, $output);
    print_r($output);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Date:23-11-2014 
            [1] => Date:24-11-2014 
            [2] => Date:26-11-2014 
            [3] => Date:27-11-2014 
            [4] => Date:27-11-2014 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23-11-2014
            [1] => 24-11-2014
            [2] => 26-11-2014
            [3] => 27-11-2014
            [4] => 27-11-2014
        )

)
```

Comment: Why downvote, please explain so i can make it better!